# wp_insert_post shows 404 (page not found)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am inserting multiple pages that are being generated trough a custom menu in the admin area.
Here is that part of the code:

```
                                $_p = array();
                                $_p['post_title'] = $the_page_title;
                                $_p['post_content'] = $the_page_content;
                                $_p['post_status'] = 'publish';
                                $_p['post_type'] = 'page';
                                $_p['comment_status'] = 'closed';
                                $_p['ping_status'] = 'closed';
                                $_p['post_category'] = array(1);
                                $the_page_id = wp_insert_post( $_p);
```

For some reason, when performing the insert in the loop, I get shown a 404 page (not an actual redirect - the URI is the same and correct, but the contents are that of the 404 page). I know this is the reason, because commenting out that line removes the issue.
And I am sure the 404 is not due to a missing page, because refreshing the page fixes the problem - the url is the same and gets opened.

I narrowed down the problem to an "error" being sent inside "parse_query" but I can't find the reason for it.

```
if ( '404' == $qv['error'] )  $this->set_404();
```

Even weirder, I tried var_dump-ing inside query.php (where parse_query is defined) and if I dump something, there is no 404 redirect - everything works fine.

I found similar questions on SO but their issues are connected to the POST parameters in their forms and in my case there are none.

Has anyone encountered such behaviour ? In what circumstances would wp_insert_post show 404 ? I'm on wordpress 4.6

Comment: `wp_insert_post()` itself _can't_ redirect the page. I'd recommend sharing more of your code...

Comment: @mevius unfortunately it can redirect. It uses the method parse_query, which inside it has a line if ( '404' == $qv['error'] ) $this->set_404(); which returns the same page as an URL but with the contents of 4o4

Comment: If anyone would explain why the question was downvoted, that would be great.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: @FDI it turned out it was something related to the hosting. I was using PHP 7.0 and a Cpanel hosting with a subdomain. However, after I created a new installation and added the same plugin, everything worked. It also works on other servers - everywhere except that installation (which is brand new)

Answer (score 0):

you must click "save permalinks" button under settings on dashboard.the button saves new pages to provide good working of them.or you can add some code to your plugin to save permalinks.just now, I fix my same problem with this way.